# Ending up with both meters and kilometers using pint in python

Tags: python, pint

Using the *pint* in code below I somehow end up with both units: `meter` and `kilometer`:

> 107661.59454231549 meter ** 1.5 / kilometer ** 0.5 / second

```py
import math
import pint

u = pint.UnitRegistry()
Q_ = u.Quantity

R_mars = 3396 * u.km
m_mars = 6.419 * 10 ** 23 * u.kg
G = 6.674 * 10 ** (-11) * u.m ** 3 / u.kg / u.s ** 2
R = 300 * u.km + R_mars

def calc_orbital_v(M, R):
    return (G * M / R) ** (1/2)

print(calc_orbital_v(m_mars, R))
```

Why does *pint* not **automatically convert** to a unified unit, either `meter` or `kilometer`?

Comment: Why should it (or how should it guess it)?
You are feeding it meters and kilometers, how should it know which to convert?
You can of course convert the answer by adding .to('weasels ** 1.5/furlong ** 0.5/fortnite')

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an automatic (implicit), but programmatic (explicit) conversion.

#### Base Units & Explicit Conversion

You could force [conversion to *base-units* of the configured *default system*](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/systems.html) by optionally setting `ureg.default_system` and using `.to_base_units()`:

```py
import math
import pint

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
Q_ = ureg.Quantity

R_mars = 3396 * ureg.km
m_mars = 6.419 * 10 ** 23 * ureg.kg
G = 6.674 * 10 ** (-11) * ureg.m ** 3 / ureg.kg / ureg.s ** 2
R = 300 * ureg.km + R_mars

def calc_orbital_v(M, R):
    return (G * M / R) ** (1/2)

speed = calc_orbital_v(m_mars, R)

print(type(speed))
print(speed)  # before: meters and kilometers mixed
print(ureg.default_system)  # the default unit system can be configured
print(speed.to_base_units())  # after: converted to base-unit meters
```

Note:

- for consistency with official *pint* docs renamed unit-registry to `ureg` (instead your given `u`)
- the unit-system defaults to `mks` (which will use `meter`s and `second`s)

Then resulting output is:

```
<class 'pint.quantity.build_quantity_class.<locals>.Quantity'>
107661.59454231549 meter ** 1.5 / kilometer ** 0.5 / second
mks
3404.558552792702 meter / second
```

The concept of *default system*s and *base unit*s seem to exist **since [version 0.7](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/commit/f65bebb6930fdd5ec891a905c30489a52add05f6#diff-aac07aefec754086f5c344e2c233862f6a611c739b5647fd456c1b77d3577c79)**.